# Can a same IPaddress be located in two different locations?

Tags: proxy, ip-address, geolocation, http-proxy

In my organizantion, there is a **proxy server**, through which all the packets are filtered and forwarded. There are many sites that tell the location of the IP address. I tried the IP addess of the proxy server and some of thease goelocation sites show the location as Chennai and some as Bangalore.

(These are cities in India).

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

IP geolocation often is very unreliable. The databases in use to achieve this service in most cases map only IP blocks and rough geographic location.

Comment: Yes, within a single country it is not reliable. But on a global scale it is even more interesting. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, please see image for details

[image]